# I can't close the gap between the side borders and the border top

Tags: css

I am creating a card that has several gradients. After a lot of work, I got the result I wanted except for the gap between the side borders and the border top.

The gap occurs when I apply border-radius, I tried to correct it by changing the px values but couldn't get the desired result.

[image]

```css
 <style>
  .gradient-border {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 289px;
}

.gradient-border::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(90, 87, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0) 100%) left,
    linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(90, 87, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0) 100%) right,
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(90, 87, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 87, 255, 1) 100%) top,
    linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        rgba(90, 87, 255, 0.01) 0%,
        rgba(90, 87, 255, 0) 50%,
        rgba(90, 87, 255, 0.01) 100%
      )
      bottom,
    radial-gradient(circle at top left, rgba(90, 87, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0) 24px),
    radial-gradient(circle at top right, rgba(90, 87, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0) 24px),
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0.1) 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(90, 87, 255, 0.1) 100%);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4px 100%, 4px 100%, 100% 4px, 100% 4px, auto auto, auto auto;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 100% 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 100%, 0px 0px, 100% 0px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.gradient-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #242366 0%, rgba(36, 35, 102, 0) 100%);
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

    </style>
```

```html
<body style="background-color: black; color: aliceblue;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; margin-right: 1rem;">
        <div class="gradient-border">
          <div class="gradient-box">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start; padding-top: 22px; padding-left: 1.5rem; padding-right: 1.5rem;">
              <p style="font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold;">title</p>
              <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; padding-top: 0.5rem;">
                <p style="font-size: 1.5em; padding-right: 1rem;">subtitle</p>
              </div>
            </div>
      
            <p style="padding-left: 1.5rem; padding-top: 0.5rem; padding-bottom: 2rem; word-break: break-all;">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis, rerum perspiciatis odio sit facere molestias? 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    
</body>
```